# How to select, trim, and store as range a word that contains the insertion point in an open Word document using the Office Add-in JavaScript API

Tags: office-js

I apologize if the answer to this basic question is obvious. I have looked everywhere and not been able to find an answer.

Say the insertion point is currently between two letters of a word in an open Word Document.  How would I assign the word (without trailing space) to a range variable using the Word Add-in JavaScript API?

For context, I am trying to make it so that the user can single click any word in the document, which would put the insertion point inside the word, and then click a UI control that executes a particular Find & Replace on that word everywhere in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the getTextRanges() method of the range to solve this. The semantic of this method is that takes the delimiters specified on the first parameter, then we go from the current insertion point both fwd and bwd until we find any of the specified delimiters and return the resulting range. Not that end of paragraph is an implicit delimiter, so this cannot go beyond a paragraph. What this means is that if the user is selecting the last word of the paragraph, that range will include a ".", so you want to make sure you validate the last characters, same is true for any other punctuation characters. Second parameter is to trim or not spaces (in my example set to true).

Here is an example of how to use it using the space (" ") as delimiter.

```js
    Word.run(function (context) { 
        var myWordRange = context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges([" "], true).getFirst();
        context.load(myWordRange);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                console.log(myWordRange.text);
             })
    })
```

Have fun..
juan.